# Display different values based on dates stored in a table in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a set of data, orders from customers on every date.

I use seasons in my company to compare sales. The seasons are not defined by the year but from certain dates ie. Season 2019 - From: 01/05/2018 - To: 30/04/2019.

The data for the Seasons (SeasonName , From , To ) are stored for all seasons (2018, 2017 etc) in another table in Access.

I want to create a field in a query of Access that checks the date of the order and if it falls between the range defined in the Seasons table, to display the equivalent SeasonName.

In Excel I would do it using index and match but in Access I need your help about it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a Calendar table. You can link your dates to this table to retrieve the corresponding SeasonName. You can generate the data for this table in Excel then import it into Access. Here's an example of a Calendar table https://www.excelcampus.com/tables/calendar-table-explained/.

The ideas are the same for Access. Build your table with your required dates and then add the SeasonName info for each date.

Comment: Thanks mate! Seems like a decenet workaround....helped for now  lot!